# Assumptions of poisson regression and log-transformation of response

Tags: generalized-linear-model, linear-model, lognormal-distribution, poisson-regression

I am trying to understand the given explanation for the below graph. It tries to make a comparison between poission regression with similar representation of a linear model.

[image]

1) When fitting a linear model with log transformed response we assume that $Var[log(Y)|X]$ is constant. How it can imply that the $Var(Y|X)$ is also constant?

Note: When fitting the linear model, they have added 0.1 to avoid the issue of zeros in the log transformation. When they are back-transforming 0.1 has been removed.

Comment: 1. Re first sentence. No, for two reasons: (i) we assume they're equal for Poisson regression, not proportional; and (ii) it's the *conditional* variance that's proportional to the conditional mean.  2. Why are you transforming rather than fitting the Poisson regression? What are you doing with the 0's? 3. Re third paragraph. You can't; the statement is incorrect (and the assumption of constant variance in the logs is false) 4. Your final sentence is unclear.

Comment: There appear to be a number of mistaken premises; and the question is written in a very unclear fashion. The question should be clarified as much as possible.

Comment: I believe a deal of additional clarification is still possible. For example, the original final sentence remains unedited.

Comment: I have edited the whole post for easy of understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When fitting a linear model with log transformed response we assume that Var[log(Y)|X] is constant. How it can imply that the Var(Y|X) is also constant?

It's not true. It is *not* the case that 
$\text{Var}(\log(Y)|X=x)$ being constant implies $\text{Var}(Y|X=x)$ is constant:

[image: Plot showing constant conditional variance in the logs is not constant variance on the original scale]

-- in fact that's only the case if the mean 
is constant.

This problem appears to be caused by the original omitting to show the fact that there's conditioning on $x$ and then forgetting that it had done so.

---

Note, however, that the assumption of constant variance on the log scale is untrue. If you generate 
data from a Poisson regression model and take logs, the conditional variance is not constant.  (and this is possibly what the text was trying to explain)

[image: plot of y vs x from Poisson regression and plot of log(y+.1) vs x]

Taking logs makes it close to linear over most of the range but the variance is definitely not constant in either of these two plots.

Incidentally if you want to add a constant when taking logs, something a little above 0.4 generally works very well, but I usually just say 0.5; it's easier to remember and close enough.

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Comment: What part? Please ask a specific question.

Comment: When fitting a linear regression with a log transformed response: $log(Y) = X\beta + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ doesn't it implies that $log(Y)|X \sim N(X\beta, \sigma^2)$?

Comment: Sure, but that's not what's being claimed.

Comment: I am bit confused with the statements given in the text. I was trying to understand it through the above conditional distribution. Will you able to explain the idea of the text in a more understandable way?

Comment: I've done what I can to explain the actual situation with some pictures but I don't know what to do to make it "more understandable" if I don't know what you don't understand.

Comment: Suppose we have a poisson response. Will you be able to explain mathematically how the variance structure will be handled in poisson regression and in linear regression with log transformation?

Comment: The variance structure for Poisson regression is handled just as it is with any other GLM; the likelihood of the particular family (in this case the Poisson, which entails the variance relationship in question) is maximized. A detailed discussion of how estimation in GLMs proceeds (maximizing likelihood of members of the exponential family) would be a new question, but if you want much detail it may end up too long even for a new question. In linear regression with a log transform, you can use ... ctd

Comment: ctd... [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) to approximate the variance of the transformed values, and then use weighted regression, where weights are proportional to the inverses of the relative variances that computation gives. That won't be maximum likelihood but if the means don't go anywhere close to zero the approximation is often quite good.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think my below post make sense in terms of the original explanation in the text.

Comment: The two sets of assumptions in the text are incompatible in their variance specifications (as my plots should make clear). Your argument for the variance of the lognormal being constant is in error (again, as my plots should make clear -- even if you can't see why your own algebra showed that you don't get constant conditional variance for $y$, the plain evidence of your eyes should tell you that you made a mistake interpreting your equation).

Answer (score 0):

```
require(faraway)
pmod <- glm(doctorco ~ sex + age +income + freepoor + illness + actdays
         + hscore, family=poisson, data=dvisits)

gmod <- lm(log(doctorco + 0.1) ~ sex + age + agesq + income + levyplus + 
freepoor + freerepa + illness + actdays + hscore + chcond1, 
          data=dvisits)
model <- step(gmod)
sigma_model <- deviance(model) / model$df.residual
plot(exp(predict(model) + sigma_model/2) - .1, predict(pmod, type="response"),
 xlab="linear model responses", ylab="poisson model responses")
abline(0, 1, col="red")
```

This is the code which generates the original scatter plot. So it seems like when they are interpreting the variance structures they have assumed a log-normal distribution for $Y$ (for linear model) and a poisson distribution for poisson regression.

For poisson: $Var(Y|X) = E(Y|X)$.

For linear model (assuming $Y$ is log-normal):
$log(Y) = X\beta + \epsilon => Var(log(Y)|X) = cons.$

$log(y_{i}) = x_{i}'\beta + \epsilon_{i}$

$y_{i} = e^{x_{i}'\beta} e^{\epsilon_{i}}$

$Var(y_{i}|x_{i}) = e^{2 x_{i}'\beta}Var(e^{\epsilon_{i}})$

Since we assumed that $\epsilon_{i}$'s are iid $N(0, \sigma^{2})$, $e^{\epsilon_{i}}$ is log-normal. Hence variance is $e^{2\sigma^2} - e^{\sigma^{2}}$ (a constant). Thereby $Var(y_{i}|x_{i})$ is a constant.

Is that make sense?

Comment: Your equation $Var(y_{i}|x_{i}) = e^{2 x_{i}'\beta}Var(e^{\epsilon_{i}})$ looks fine ... but that's *definitely* not constant. You made a mistake in between that line and the conclusion.

Comment: From your first set of plots I can see that even when the constant variance assumption is satisfied, once you take the exponential it is not going to have constant variance at the end. Oh..Is it because of the exponential term in front of the variance term?

Comment: Correct. That term is the square of the mean. So the conditional standard deviation is proportional to the mean -- which is why it spreads the way it does -- the $e^\epsilon$ multiplicative noise term is essentially a percentage-variability (e.g. if  $e^\epsilon=1.1$ it means the observed value is 10% above the mean and if it's 0.9 the observed value is 10% below the mean)